# using array element as string value

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSMutableArray *test

I am able to add objects to the array, and to NSLog the array and see this working.

Trying to use a value form the array to show in a label I have:

```
    self.topscore.text = test[0];
```

However when I run this i get sigarbt error. My first thought was that there might not be anything in the array to get, so before the label definition I tried to set in a few numbers manually:

```
test = @[@1,@2];
```

But here I get 'Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray*'

Comment: please list the rest of the code that assigns any actual values, sigabrt could mean array has NO values.

Comment: Using the shortcut syntax of  @[item1, item 2, ...] gives you an NSArray NOT an NSMutableArray. To get the latter use `@[...].mutableCopy`.

Comment: In my implementation part in top i have NSMutableArray *test;
then I just want to add the first two elements, I don't get why I would need a mutableCopy for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And you can show them on label like this

```
self.topscore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",names[0]];
```

You cannot add elements to nsmutable array like that.

```
NSMutableArray *names2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
```

Comment: That last part is giving me troubles - I updated the question